# Is it possible to authenticate a device with a server without the device knowing any sort of secret?

Tags: authentication, api, secrets-management, zero-trust

Pretty much what the title says. I have been playing around with discord webhooks lately and one problem I have discovered is that anyone with the webhook url/token can send messages. This means that if I were to write an application that sends a webhook to discord, anyone who has access to the application also has access to the webhook url and can send messages with it.

One solution I have been toying with is using a separate server to manage the webhook, where all client applications send their content to the server in order to post the webhook, however if someone were to decompile the application they would still be able to obtain the secrets required to authenticate with the server and send messages.

How could this be done in a way where the client application has no knowlage of the secrets required but still can authenticate securely with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a client-server approach for that, without the need to keep secrets on the client.

The server holds the application that uses the webhook and posts messages, and maintains a list of approved clients. The clients don't have the webhook secret, but an account to talk to the server. This account could be a long random string that cannot be predicted by other clients. If you allow only pre-approved clients to send messages by using a registration system, your webhook is safe and your client application don't need any secret.

If anyone gets the client application code, it will not gain access to the server, only maybe the account ID of that particular client. And if a client abuses the system, you revoke its account.

Comment: I'd say the long random string which mustn't be known by other clients *is* a secret, but of course your suggestion makes perfect sense. It seems the OP's actual problem wasn't secretless authentication but rather granularity of access.

Comment: Yes, every client have its own secret. That's why it should be long and random, so nobody can predict it.

Comment: That partially solves the problem, but it doesn’t proactively prevent abuse, banning a client after it abuses the webhook means that you can still get away with sending at least one message before you get kicked out. However I have no idea how you would stop an unauthorized message from being sent without keeping a secret on the client device.

Comment: You can have rate-limiting, you can have daily limits, you can scan the messages before sending, you can put them into a queue and manually allowing them. The idea of a client ID isn't to proactively prevent abuse, but to keep the webhook secret.

Comment: Fair enough, I might also be able to set up one time use keys that are sent down from the server when it expects a message. Thank you!